# Bootstrap form, columns not working as expected for required fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form that will show an error message box in a form with validation.

I cannot seem to make the error box fit the exact same width as the form (label -input) columns. It seems to be off no matter what I do. So for the time being I have left it as col-sm-12. Can someone explain to me why I cannot seem to get this to match the width of the label and input width ?

I am also having the same issue with the required spans. I am trying to get the "require text" to line up under the input boxes. No matter what I do this just will not work. I can pad left to make it fit per each size but this seems silly as I would think the frame work using the cols should do it for me? Can someone help me as to what I am missing. I am fairly new to bootstrap and I am just stumped. If I put class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offest-2 on the required span it doesnt do anything stays the same as class="col-sm-12". I am guessing it needs to stay within the  when I pull it out things go nuts...

here is a sample of the label input and required span, the only thing I could get to work right is col-sm-12 so that it at least lined up with something but it looks ridiculous.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="InputAddress1">Address 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offest-2  input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" autofocus required>
        </div>                                                                                                                            
        <span class="error col-sm-12">Required</span>
  </div>
```

full code sample can be viewed here
https://stevia-affirm.codio.io/Question.html

Thank you 
Gina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you have with the Require is that you have a typo (and maybe you did copy and paste to repeat the error on the required span?).

You don't need the offset in the input-group since the col-sm-2 for the label is already there.  If you corrected the typo, you'd get something ugly because you have too many columns then (i.e., 2+ 2+ 9 = 13).  Just drop the offset there.

Then you can add the offset to your required (without the typo ;-):

```
<span class="error col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">Required</span>
```

Also, your well is the width of the form.  It may not look like it because of the right aligned labels and the fact that each of your label+inputs only add up to 11 instead of 12.

EDIT:  Here's a cleaned up version of the form (most of it).  You'll notice that I wrapped the input groups in separate classes for the columns.  The reason for this is the combination of using form-horizontal and the input-group-addons, makes the input be 100%+the fixed width of the addon element.  Wrapping everything like this will produce the result you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Employee Information</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top:30px;">
                <div class="alert alert-danger ">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert "></span><strong> message</strong>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk "></i></span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name " class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="InputAddress1">Address 1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" autofocus required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="error col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="InputAddress2">Address 2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon_width"><i class=""></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="InputCity">City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk form-control-feedback"></i></span>
                        <input ng-model="demo.city" ng-disabled="!editAllowed" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span ng-show="demographics_form.city.$error.required" class="error col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="InputState">State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk form-control-feedback"></i></span>
                        <select id="state" class="form-control" required>
                            <option >State</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-hide="!editAllowed" class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button  class="btn btn-info btn-block">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that however removing it I still the issue ? I am still baffled as to how to make it line up correctly...  What is the proper way to do it? again i would think the framework would do this?

Comment: I updated my answer for you with a cleaned up sample of your form.

Comment: Thank you so much, I now see what you did :) and works as I would expect it.